# Replace Character with Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

**Goal**: Replace consecutive asterisks with the count of them surrounded by the `sup` tag.

**Input**

```
Hello, my name is Chris Happy*. My profile picture is a happy face.**

*: It's not my actual name, but a nickname.
**: Well, my "last name" is happy, so I think it's fitting.
```

**Output**

```
Hello, my name is Chris Happy<sup>1</sup>. My profile picture is a happy face.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup>: It's not my actual name, but a nickname.
<sup>2</sup>: Well, my "last name" is happy, so I think it's fitting.
```

How could I efficiently accomplish this?

Comment: What duplicates is it you want to remove?

Comment: Not "duplicate consecutive characters" but "count and replace _a specific character_"? If you want to count duplicate consecutive characters you'll get a hit for the `p`s in `happy`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, wouldn't the first one match on `my`, `name` and `a`, and the second one would match on `my`, `name`, `is` and `happy` ? If it's just supposed to match a name, how would you know what a name is ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with `replace` and the callback function can count the length of the match:

```
txt = txt.replace(/\*+/g, m => `<sup>${m.length}</sup>`);
```

Demo:

```js
var txt = `Hello, my name is Chris Happy*. My profile picture is a happy face.**

*: It's not my actual name, but a nickname.
**: Well, my "last name" is happy, so I think it's fitting.`;

txt = txt.replace(/\*+/g, m => `<sup>${m.length}</sup>`);

console.log(txt);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple implementation.  Some may call it brute force, but I think it's more peace of mind.

```js
var string = `Hello, my name is Chris Happy*. My profile picture is a happy face.**
*: It's not my actual name, but a nickname.
**: Well, my "last name" is happy, so I think it's fitting.`;

// Loop through the total string length because it may consist of only duplicates.
for (var i = string.length; i > 0; i--)
      string = string.replace(new RegExp("\\*{" + i + "}", "g"), "<sup>" + i + "</sup>");
// Display the string
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML= string;
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace only astriks you can use this simple RegExp:

```js
var str = "Hello, my name is Chris Happy*. My profile picture is a happy face.**";
str = str.replace(/(\*)+/g, rep);

function rep(matches) {
  return '<sup>' + matches.length + '</sup>';
}
console.log(str);
```

Output:

```
 Hello, my name is Chris Happy<sup>1</sup>. My profile picture is a happy face.<sup>2</sup>.
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7n9nuw3a/):  (look at the console)